# Can someone explain what this following regex means

Tags: javascript, regex

`/(.*?)((http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)*){1}(.*?)/g`

I could only make some assumptions about the above regex. But most of it is cryptic to me.

`(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)` - It contains either `http` or `https` protocol.

`[a-zA-Z]{2,6}` - Contain any of the lower or uppercase characters between 2 and 6 times.

`/g` - Search for it recursively

But was not able to put all of the blocks together.

Comment: Check it out on [regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/Hgte75/1)

Comment: Paste it in: https://regexper.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it's trying to match full URLs.

- `(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?`, as you mentioned, looks for an optional protocol prefix
- `(.*?)` at the beginning and end match anything that may be before or after the URLs.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+` is likely attempting to match domain names and sub-domains (e.g. `test.us.domain`)
- `\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}` is matches top-level domains (e.g. `.com`, `.us`, `.ninja`)
- `(\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+)*` is looking for paths (e.g. `/about`, `/files/my-file001.txt`)
- `{1}` just one

This regex has it's faults for this purpose, for example some of the segments that allow `.` characters (e.g. `[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+`) would allow for them multiple times in a row (i.e. `a...c...d`) but generally speaking this should match on URLs provided the data around them doesn't look too much like URLs.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think your explanation and spending a bit more time on the regex makes sense now.